# Angular: how to achieve rendering HTML from variable with SSR?

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml, server-side-rendering

I currently render some HTML from a string using `innerHTML`. But this is executed client side, so the content of my div never gets server-side rendered.

I'd like to know if there is an alternative method to using `innerHTML` so that my HTML code gets server-side rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to do that you may include a specific library for SSR. Angular provides Angular Universal, you can read more about it here https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already use SSR with universal, that's not the problem. The problem is that innerHTML is a client side function and is not supported by universal so I need an alternative that works with it.